# Undefined route.params when navigating inside nested navigators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I'm using React Native and React Navigation. I'm attempting to only make one of my screens into `mode="Modal`, but the route params I pass when navigating are getting "undefined" with the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'route.params.title')`. Why is this and how can I fix this?

**My Attempt**

```js
const ModalScreen = () => (
  <Modals.Navigator mode="modal">
    <Modals.Screen
      name="Modal"
      component={Modal}
      options={({ route }) => ({
        title: route.params.title,
        headerTransparent: true,
        gestureResponseDistance: {
          vertical: 500,
        },
      })}
    />
  </Modals.Navigator>
);
const MainScreen = () => (
  <Items.Navigator>
    <Items.Screen
      name="Main"
      component={Main}
      options={{ headerShown: false }}
    />
    <Items.Screen name="Modal" component={ModalScreen} />
  </Items.Navigator>
);

// Navigating to Modal in another file.
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() =>
    navigation.navigate("Modal", {
      screen: "Modal",
      title: title,
    })
  }
>
```

Answer (score 10):

When you are sending parameters to nested navigators you have to send it like below

```
      navigation.navigate('Modal', {
        screen: 'Modal',
        params: { title: 'title' },
      })
```

The key params specifies that its a parameter, and you can access it like any other parameter.

Comment: None of my options on ModalScreen are working though, any ideas why?

Comment: i cant think of a reason, but revert that change and try with a hardcoded value for the title instead of the param

Comment: Thank you @GuruparanGiritharan, working perfectly, should be accepted as solution!

Answer (score 0):

the reason its not working is because your param is on the parent stack and not on the route itself since you navigated from one stack to another

react navigation provides a dangerouslyGetParent method to solve this problem
[react navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dangerouslygetparent)

Comment: What do you mean by "your param is on the parent stack and not on the route itself"? The parent stack should be the MainScreen stack, right? And the route goes from MainScreen to ModalScreen. Since I'm specifying the screen in the ModalScreen stack, shouldn't the params be on the route?